# Cannot fully install nvidia or Xorg videodrivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, kde, nvidia-geforce

I have a problem installing NVidia drivers. It gives me an output that i'm possibly missing firmware in i915.[image] . And when I try it through software sources it gives me pk-client-error-quark: error while installing package: subproces from package intramfs-tools script post-intallation returned errorvalue 1 (313).[image]

So I downloaded firmware from [enter link description here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/i915). And I unpacked the tarball. But don't know how to reinstall the i915 package. Please tell me how to install this.

It also won't fully install the Xorg driver ( same errorvalue 1 (313)).

I think I need to reinstall the i915 package in order to install the nvidia drivers correctly.  But I'm not sure.

Does anybody have a solution for me how to solve this.

I run
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.11.0-40-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB
NVidia GeForce 250 MX (GP108M)/Intel Integrated GPU on HP Envy 17 ce1000 (laptop)

Edit 211215

```
    patrick@Lappy:~$ dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'
Gevraagd=(U)onbekend/(I)nstalleren/ve(R)wijderen/(P)wissen/(H)ouden
| Status=Niet/Inst/Conf/Uitgep/halF-geconf/Halfgeïnst/verWacht-trig/Trig-bezig
|/ Fout?=(geen)/heRinst. nodig/ (Status,Fout: hoofdletter=ernstig)
+++-=================================================-=============================================-============-==========================================================================================================
hi  0ad   0.0.23.1-4ubuntu3    amd64        Real-time strategy game of ancient warfare    
iF  initramfs-tools    0.136ubuntu6.6   all     generic modular initramfs generator (automation)       
iF  linux-image-5.11.0-43-generic                     5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic   
iU  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-41-generic        5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1+1                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-41    
iF  nvidia-kernel-common-470                          470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                       amd64
```

Shared files used with the kernel module

```
patrick@Lappy:~$ sudo update-grub   
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'   
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'   
Generating grub configuration file ...   
using custom appearance settings   
Found background image: /boot/grub/themes/Background.png    
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.5-051505-generic   
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.5-051505-generic    
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.4-051504-generic   
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.4-051504-generic   
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-5.4-liquorix-amd64   
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-5.4-liquorix-amd64   
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-5.3-liquorix-amd64   
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-5.3-liquorix-amd64   
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-43-generic   
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic   
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic   
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-40-generic   
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-40-generic   
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi   
Found Linux Mint 20.2 Uma (20.2) on /dev/nvme0n1p9   
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings   
done
```

```
    patrick@Lappy:~$ dkms status
```

```
patrick@Lappy:~$ sudo apt update    
[sudo] password for patrick:     
Geraakt:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                         
Geraakt:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                            
Ophalen:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                   
Geraakt:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                       
Geraakt:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cubic-wizard/release/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                       
Ophalen:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]                            
Geraakt:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damentz/liquorix/ubuntu focal InRelease   
Ophalen:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]       
Geraakt:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease       
Geraakt:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu focal InRelease       
Geraakt:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp-beta/ubuntu focal InRelease       
Geraakt:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Geraakt:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/test/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Geraakt:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xtradeb/play/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Ophalen:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [12,9 kB]   
Geraakt:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu focal InRelease                                
349 kB opgehaald in 4s (91,4 kB/s)     
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar     
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd           
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar     
Alle pakketten zijn up-to-date.     
patrick@Lappy:~$
```

The update today gave me the 5.11.0-43 Kernel, so after the download I did a 'update-grub'. But I see it didn't make the initrd.img.

The DKMS status however, I don't know, doesn't give me any output. Is it a file, if so, what is it called ( I searched for dkms status and did not find it ).

Edit 211217

I uninstalled the kernel 5.11.0-43 because it appeared to be not installed the right way.

```
patrick@Lappy:~$ dpkg -l | grep initramfs-tools
iF  initramfs-tools                                   0.136ubuntu6.6                                all          generic modular initramfs generator (automation)
ii  initramfs-tools-bin                               0.136ubuntu6.6                                amd64        binaries used by initramfs-tools
ii  initramfs-tools-core                              0.136ubuntu6.6                                all          generic modular initramfs generator (core tools)
patrick@Lappy:~$ tree /var/lib/dkms/
/var/lib/dkms/
└── dkms_dbversion

0 directories, 1 file
patrick@Lappy:~$ dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|i|h|m]'   
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                         2.34-6ubuntu1.3                               amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target   
ii  linux-headers-5.11.0-40-generic                   5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP      
ii  linux-headers-5.11.0-41-generic                   5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-5.3-liquorix-amd64           5.15-5ubuntu1~focal                           amd64        Header files for Linux 5.15.0-5.3-liquorix-amd64   
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-5.4-liquorix-amd64           5.15-6ubuntu1~focal                           amd64        Header files for Linux 5.15.0-5.4-liquorix-amd64   
ii  linux-headers-5.15.4-051504                       5.15.4-051504.202111211331                    all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.15.4   
ii  linux-headers-5.15.4-051504-generic               5.15.4-051504.202111211331                    amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.15.4 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
ii  linux-headers-5.15.5-051505                       5.15.5-051505.202111250933                    all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.15.5   
ii  linux-headers-5.15.5-051505-generic               5.15.5-051505.202111250933                    amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.15.5 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
ii  linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-40                  5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.11.0   
ii  linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-41                  5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.11.0   
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-27-generic                     5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic    
ii  linux-image-5.11.0-40-generic                     5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic    
ii  linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic                     5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic   
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-5.3-liquorix-amd64             5.15-5ubuntu1~focal                           amd64        Linux 5.15 for 64-bit PCs   
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-5.4-liquorix-amd64             5.15-6ubuntu1~focal                           amd64        Linux 5.15 for 64-bit PCs   
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.4-051504-generic        5.15.4-051504.202111211331                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.15.4 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.5-051505-generic        5.15.5-051505.202111250933                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.15.5 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-27-generic                   5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
ii  linux-modules-5.11.0-40-generic                   5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
ii  linux-modules-5.11.0-41-generic                   5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
ii  linux-modules-5.15.4-051504-generic               5.15.4-051504.202111211331                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.4 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
ii  linux-modules-5.15.5-051505-generic               5.15.5-051505.202111250933                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.5 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-27-generic             5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-40-generic             5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-41-generic             5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP   
iU  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-41-generic        5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1+1                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-41
```

I got the Liqourix kernels after seeing a Chris Titus video on youtube. Can't remember how I got them though. As you can see I keep 2 newer kernels, 2 Liqourix and 2 original Kubuntu kernels. Now I'm using the 5.11.0-41. I got the newer kernels after reading on a forum that they had more driver for fingerprint readers. The Synaptics fp-reader is still not working though. ( No problem. )

Edit 211218
patrick@Lappy:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install
[sudo] password for patrick:
Instellen van initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Instellen van linux-firmware (1.187.23) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic with 1.
dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket linux-firmware (--configure):
subproces van pakket linux-firmware werd script post-installation geïnstalleerd gaf de foutwaarde 1 terug
Instellen van linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1) ...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic with 1.
dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket initramfs-tools (--configure):
subproces van pakket initramfs-tools werd script post-installation geïnstalleerd gaf de foutwaarde 1 terug
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:

- dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.11.0-41-generic
  ...done.
  /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
  update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
  E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
  update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic with 1.
  run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
  dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (--configure):
  subproces van pakket linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic werd script post-installation geïnstalleerd gaf de foutwaarde 1 terug
  Fouten gevonden tijdens verwerken van:
  linux-firmware
  initramfs-tools
  linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic

EDIT 211220

patrick@Lappy:~$ sudo apt -f install
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar
Vereisten worden gecorrigeerd... Klaar
De volgende extra pakketten zullen geïnstalleerd worden:
initramfs-tools-bin
De volgende pakketten zullen opgewaardeerd worden:
initramfs-tools-bin
1 opgewaardeerd, 0 nieuw geïnstalleerd, 0 te verwijderen en 0 niet opgewaardeerd.
3 niet volledig geïnstalleerd of verwijderd.
Er moeten 0 B/10,9 kB aan archieven opgehaald worden.
Na deze bewerking zal er 2.048 B extra schijfruimte gebruikt worden.
Wilt u doorgaan? [J/n] j
(Database wordt ingelezen ... 258005 bestanden en mappen momenteel geïnstalleerd.)
Uitpakken van .../initramfs-tools-bin_0.136ubuntu6.6_amd64.deb wordt voorbereid...
Bezig met uitpakken van initramfs-tools-bin (0.136ubuntu6.6) over (0.136ubuntu6) ...
Instellen van initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Instellen van linux-firmware (1.187.23) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic with 1.
dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket linux-firmware (--configure):
subproces van pakket linux-firmware werd script post-installation geïnstalleerd gaf de foutwaarde 1 terug
Instellen van linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1) ...
Instellen van initramfs-tools-bin (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic with 1.
dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket initramfs-tools (--configure):
subproces van pakket initramfs-tools werd script post-installation geïnstalleerd gaf de foutwaarde 1 terug
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:

- dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.11.0-41-generic
  ...done.
  /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
  update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
  E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
  update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic with 1.
  run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
  dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (--configure):
  subproces van pakket linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic werd script post-installation geïnstalleerd gaf de foutwaarde 1 terug
  Fouten gevonden tijdens verwerken van:
  linux-firmware
  initramfs-tools
  linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

So it still gives me the error code (1)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `dkms status` also `sudo apt update` and `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` as text in codeblock. Not as anpicture please.

Comment: The "possible firmware missing" is a warning, not an error, as is normal unless you have one of the cards mentioned. Please [edit] the question and add the info requested above because you have some other issues with the installed packages that prevent the correct installation of any software, not just Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Oh many ppa's.  `wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools-bin_0.136ubuntu6_amd64.deb` try to install it with `sudo dpkg -i initramfs-tools-bin_0.136ubuntu6_amd64.deb`  Only when this works `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: @ nobody. Thanks for editing and your reply. Did what you wrote, still don't get a respons in the terminal for 'dkms status'. Should I get rid of some of these ppa's? Or leave them in case of some updates/upgrades?

Comment: are initramfs-tools correct installed now? `dpkg -l | grep initramfs-tools`  and `tree /var/lib/dkms/` also please  `dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|i|h|m]'` where did you get this kernel? `initrd.img-5.15.0-5.4-liquorix-amd64`

Comment: @ nobody. I edited my op. Thank you again.

Comment: please boot up a standart (from ubuntu sources) kernel and remove any packages with 5.15.5 in name like linux-modules-5.15.4-051504-generic  and the others with `sudo dpkg -P linux-modules-5.15.4-051504-generic (and so on)` I hope it works (but initramfs-tools have to be correct installt) . If you are unsure make a simulation first `dpkg --simulate -P your packages-names`

Comment: That gives me this:                                                                              patrick@Lappy:~$ sudo dpkg -P linux-modules-5.15.4-051504-generic
[sudo] password for patrick: 
dpkg: vereistenproblemen verhinderen het verwijderen van linux-modules-5.15.4-051504-generic:
 linux-image-unsigned-5.15.4-051504-generic is afhankelijk van linux-modules-5.15.4-051504-generic.

So I uninstalled them with Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer. I have 5.11.0-40-generic and 5.11.0-41-generic left.

Comment: to make it more clear you have to give all packages at once `sudo dpkg -P package1 package2 package3 and so on`

Comment: Oh than that's probably why it didn't work. I got rid of them with Mainline. They are uninstalled.

Comment: `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install` please.

Comment: Thanks again for your precious time. Maybe I should make a list of my installed software and do a clean install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was  `plymouth`. I purged it and reinstalled it. Now everything is fine. I could install the driver and the X-settings are working as well. I want to thank nobody for all the help and time invested. Gave his answer and comments already arrows up.

Answer (score 1):

first we remove every remaining conf files from deinstallt packages.

```
sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | egrep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Then we try again to install initramfs-tools.

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools-bin_0.136ubuntu6_amd64.deb
```

we need this package fully installed.

```
sudo dpkg -i initramfs-tools-bin_0.136ubuntu6_amd64.deb
```

Only the this works without error!! (If not make a backup and install anew)

```
sudo apt -f install
```

for the future do not following youtube tutorials :D