# My kernel is not being upgraded

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, kernel, kubuntu

When updating/upgrading I used to get kernel updates once in a while. Now I haven't got any kernel updates since December. 
 I only put 0ad 0.23 on hold ( since I have 0.25 as a snap, and they both have different mods so I want both versions ). 
Does anyone have an idea what is causing apt/apt-get/aptitude not to get newer kernels? I had a problem with `Plymouth` that messed with installing new software, but that is solved now. [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380977/cannot-fully-install-nvidia-or-xorg-videodrivers)I can update and (un)install software/drivers now, no problem. Only I'm still on the 5.11.0-41 kernel ( Kubuntu 20.04.2 ). It's not a very big deal ( since the newer kernels will not support my fingerprint reader either ), but since everything else is up to date ...
Any ideas please, what could be the cause.

I ran `apt policy linux-image` and `sudo apt policy linux-image`:

```
patrick@Lappy:~$ apt policy linux-image     
linux-image:           
  Geïnstalleerd: (geen)      
  Kandidaat:     (geen)     
  Versietabel:
patrick@Lappy:~$
```

( Installed: none    Candidate: none   Versiontable:-  )
Although I put my systemsetting to `English-American` the output is in Dutch. Did sign out and sign in again, like it said. Sorry for that. 
Took a screenshot of mainline. See picture[image].
I already looked at these posts:[enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984902/no-fix-to-kernel-that-stopped-updating-on-its-own?rq=1)and [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175385/why-is-apt-no-longer-updating-the-kernel). The new kernel it wants to install is 5.4.0-99-generic. Seems odd to me, while I'm on 5.11.0-41right now to install a 5.4.0-99 kernel. This installation (Kubuntu 20.04.2) standard came with 5.8.0-27 if I remember it right. To me this raises more questions than answers. 
Does the uninstall of kernel 5.11.0-43 have anything to do with it? (it kernelpaniced so I uninstalled this one , and if yes, where can I find this history/log?)

edit 220220/15.10

```
patrick@Lappy:~$ dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|h|i|m]'
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                         2.34-6ubuntu1.3                               amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  linux-headers-5.11.0-40-generic                   5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.11.0-41-generic                   5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-40                  5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.11.0
ii  linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-41                  5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.11.0
ii  linux-image-5.11.0-40-generic                     5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic                     5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-modules-5.11.0-40-generic                   5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.11.0-41-generic                   5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-40-generic             5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-41-generic             5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-41-generic        5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1+1                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-41

patrick@Lappy:~$ LANG=ENG
patrick@Lappy:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease           
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease          
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cubic-wizard/release/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/test/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xtradeb/play/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
patrick@Lappy:~$ 

patrick@Lappy:~$ sudo apt install linux-generic-eol-hwe-5.11
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-eol-hwe-5.11
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-generic-eol-hwe-5.11'
patrick@Lappy:~$
```

Comment: please show the output of "apt policy linux-image"

Comment: Run `uname –sr` to view Linux version. If it is version 5.8 (and if you are using Ubuntu 20.04.2) Ubuntu will only support up to 5.8. If it is just 20.04, it only supports 5.4. This is according to https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Ubuntu_LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack_information

Don't know how accurate this information is, so take my word as a grain of salt.

Comment: @Jeff  It is kernel 5.11.0-41 which was automaticly updated in December.

Comment: @JoepieEs Alright. My source sucks. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jeff  No problem. He doesn't talk about automatic updates. Thanks for the source though. He might have some other interesting stuff.

Comment: Can we have the output of "apt policy linux-image" as previously requested?  It would take the guesswork out of the situation.

Comment: @ leggewie. It's in the post. Only it's still displaying dutch although I put systemsettings to english-us. I put a translation below it. The layout sucks a bit, don't know what is going on with that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|h|i|m]'` not as picture. and also `sudo apt update`

Comment: @nobody edited my question

Comment: `sudo apt install linux-generic-eol-hwe-5.11`

Comment: @nobody edited my question. Only thing I don't get is the 'eol' part. Since I'm on 20.04.2 LTS. But anyway put the output in my question.

Comment: Oh, forget it, did not see it is only awailable from focal-proposed (no, do not add it).

Comment: @nobody Why OP should not add it?

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your time and sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper meta packages are not installed for some reason.

Run

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

and you'll get kernel upgrades.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Result:```patrick@Lappy:~$ uname -r --->
5.13.0-30-generic
patrick@Lappy:~$ ```